# Django: dbbackup displays pg_dump: error: too many command-line arguments

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've installed the `django-dbbackup` package and from what the [Documentation](https://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.0/installation.html) tells, i need to run `python manage.py dbbackup`

but it generated error `pg_dump: error: too many command-line arguments`

from what i have seen in the logs

```
dbbackup.db.exceptions.CommandConnectorError: Error running:  pg_dump database_name --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean
```

From what i have known, the correct command for pg_dump is to include the database name in the last part but the dbbackup include the database name first.

Anyone know the fix for the Django-dbbackup?

Comment: How is this related to programming? What code of your is involved?

Comment: Perhaps you need to upgrade your version of django-dbbackup: https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup/issues/229. The documentation version you link to is very old.

Comment: @solarissmoke using `pip install -e git+https://github.com/mjs7231/django-dbbackup.git#egg=django-dbbackup` didnt know that pip install django-dbbackup is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. What I did was

1. Made sure pg_dump was in the environment variable in my system.
2. pip uninstall dbbackup
3. pip install django-dbbackup --upgrade

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with you, this is my env

- Window 10
- postgres10
- django 2.2.9
- django-dbbackup 3.2.0

I can manual run successfully like below, add "--dbname" parm name.

```
pg_dump --dbname=database_name --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --username=postgres --no-password --clean
```

I don't know how to override the command by create a new method, so I changed the source code in dbbackup package directly, it works.

file "\Lib\site-packages\dbbackup\db\postgresql.py"

from:

```
    cmd = '{} --dbname={}'.format(self.dump_cmd, self.settings['NAME'])
```

to:

```
    cmd = '{} {}'.format(self.dump_cmd, self.settings['NAME'])
```